# Limit integral w/ sine function

Tags: limits, definite-integrals

Here's a random problem I thought of:

$$\lim_{\alpha\to 0}\int_0^{\infty}\sin(\alpha x) \;\mathrm{d}x$$

What I'm trying to create is a sine function with an "infinite period", meaning instead of the period being $2\pi$ the period is infinity (maybe this doesn't make sense at all). I would think the integral might exist, because if there is a period then there are places where the function crosses the x-axis, meaning it is possible to evaluate the integral, but I don't know for sure because the period is infinity.

**Edit:** based on matt's comment, here is a different way to look at it:

$$\lim_{\alpha\to 0+}\int_0^{\frac {1}{\alpha}}\sin(\alpha x) \;\mathrm{d}x$$

Comment: $\int_0^{\infty} \sin(\alpha x) dx$ doesn't even exist when $\alpha >0$. So, that limit doesn't make sense.

Comment: Perhaps rewrite the problem $\lim_{\alpha\to 0^+} \int^{g(\alpha)}_0 \sin (\alpha x) dx,$with some function $g$ where $g(\alpha)\to \infty$ as $\alpha \to 0^+.$

Comment: I am not sure the rewrite captures your question, as you seemed to be after a single "infinitely long period", instead of "infinitely many" "infinitely short" periods...

Comment: Not that it isn't a good question, just rather that it doesn't seem that it is necessarily analogous to your first question..

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\int_0^{\infty} \sin(ax)dx$ doesn't exist for all $a \neq 0$. Hence, the limit also doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Matt's comment we can change the limits of integration by root(1/alpha), as we can see we can calculate the integral and evaluate the limit using the L'Hôpital rule, obtaining a limit equal to 1/2, but if we follow the integral form proposed by Matt, we find that the limit in this case is +infinity, given that the limit is unique the we deduce that the limit asked doesn't exist.